# Algoritmo em C verificar se um período digitado (data de início e fim) não se sobrepõe, ainda que parcialmente, a um período previamente cadastrado

Tags: c, algoritmo

Galera estou criando um algoritmo de sistema e controle de hotéis em C para um trabalho da faculdade , no módulo de reservas preciso realizar reservas dos quartos entre data início data fim e quando  for realizar outra reserva não pode atingir o período anterior (data início-data fim já cadastrado),  alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Talvez, considerando que início e fim estejam em ordem crescente, possa ser um período válido: `if ((fim < inicio_cadastrado) || (inicio > fim_cadastrado)) `.

Comment: Eu tentei desse jeito já mas ainda não dá perfeitamente para certas datas

Comment: Explique em quais casos "não dá perfeitamente".